# AS3/Air: PNG > File > FileStream > ByteArray > BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, air, filestream, bitmapdata

I want to use FileSteam.open() to synchronously read image files from disk. I can then get them into a ByteArray with readBytes(), but I can't find how to get that into BitmapData. I know Image can read it as is, but I need BitmapData.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sounds exiting ... looking forward to your results ... :)

Comment: very cool ... any plans on releasing it? it would be a great ammendment to both as3corelib and hxformat ...

i think interlacing is not really needed ... as far as i know, both loading or embedding interlaced PNGs doesn't work either, so - except for perfectionism - why expect more?

Comment: I haven't gotten to finishing this yet... BUT I did see that there's a new async loading routine in Flash 11 which might make this way more niche than it already was since it seems to handle bitmapData.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the package `flash.display`, use `Loader::loadBytes` ... that'll give you a `Bitmap`, and the `BitmapData` can then be simply accessed through `Bitmap::bitmapData` ... this makes the whole operation asynchronous, of course ... the only thing you could do, is write a decoder yourself ...

now there is a PNG **encoder** in AS3, in the as3corelib and i guess there are even others, but probably most people considered it pointless to write a decoder, since flash does this in its own, and also encoding is easier than decoding, because decoding means, you have to implement the whole format ... still, you can give it a shot of course ...

well, hope that helps ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Thanks again. ::sigh:: So I guess there's no straight-forward way for me to synchronously load BitmapData then?

Comment: i'm afraid no ... if you find one, please tell me ... :)
you can always hope, hxformat (http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/) will one day finally include a PNG decoder and then compile an swc that you can use in your project, but until then, i don't even know of a lib doing the job for you ... or maybe, one day there will be a synchronous version of `Loader::loadBytes` (which would really be VERY cool in some scenarios) ... good luck anyway ... ;)

Comment: I spent a day on a PNG decoder. Never done that before. I got most of it done ( messily ), but undoing the filtering is a little tricky. I have more important things to make progress on at the moment, but if I get time to finish it later, I'll let you know.

Comment: I keep looking at the PNGDecoder... and while it sorta works - it gets all the chunks and what not... the thought of implementing all of the different types of interlacing is a bit above me at the moment. I'm using loadBytes from the synchronously loaded PNG data.

PNG > File > FileStream > ByteArray > Loader.loadBytes > BitmapData

Answer (score 0):

This library on github has a PNGDecoder that works synchronously.  Give it a try:

https://github.com/terrynoya/ASImageLib

From the usage wiki:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = [PNG bytes];
var bmpData:BitmapData = new PNGDecoder().decode(bytes);
this.addChild(new Bitmap(bmpData));
```

But I'd imagine using the built-in class would be faster, and while it depends on your use-case, typically when dealing with UI like images, asynchronous is preferred to avoid blocking the UI thread (causing the app to stutter).  But there could be some use cases.

Answer (score -1):

It have sense, because FileStream works to manage pure data, and BitmapData works for compile or decompile data.

The way Im about to use, is to read the file in the origin and write a temporary file in the application directory, which may be reached by Loader class without troubles.

Wish me luck!

Comment: Good luck! Let us know if you find out anything useful.